# Music on lag baomer

Tags: halacha, sefirat-ha-omer, music, evening-night, lag-ba-omer

Are you allowed to listen to music the night of lag baomer or do you have to wait untill the day?

Answer (score 5):

*See* Moishe Dovid Lebovits, "[Lag B'Omer](https://www.5tjt.com/featured-news/6950-lag-bomer.html)," 5 Towns Jewish Times:

> **Night or Day**. Many have the custom to
> make the bonfires (and dancing) on the
> night of Lag B’omer. Others say that
> the simcha should start at day.85
> However, it seems that the minhag is
> to conduct the bonfire and dancing at
> night all over the world, not only in
> Meron.86  However, music in the
> absence of a bonfire is prohibited
> until the next day after neitz
> hachamah.87
>
> 85: Harav Yisrael Belsky Shlita, opinion of Harav Korelitz Shlita quoted in Doleh U’mashka page 194:footnote 520.
>
> 86: Harav Yisrael Belsky Shlita, see Mekadesh Yisrael 103, Chut Shani Shabbos 4:page 380, Doleh U’mashka pages 194-195 footnote 521. The Halichos Shlomo Moadim 2:page 362:footnote 23 says dancing is permitted on Lag B’omer even if it is not for a devar mitzvah (refer to Ben Pesach L’Shavuos 15:4:footnote 4). The Avnei Yushpei 1:98 is not convinced that dancing is permitted at all after Lag B’omer.
>
> 87: Refer to Doleh U’mashka page 194:footnote 520, Mekadesh Yisrael 103.

Comment: this is Halachically Speaking Volume 3 Issue 16: http://www.thehalacha.com/attach/Volume3/Issue16.pdf

Answer (score 3):

> בליל ל''ג בעומר ולמחרתו נוהגים להקל לשמוע שירים מכלי נגינה, וכל שכן מטייפ, לכבוד ההילולא של התנא רשב''י ע''ה.‏
>   [חזון עובדיה על יום טוב מהדורת תשס''ג, עמוד רנח]

According to Maran Hacham Ovadia Shelit"a it is Mutar, l'kavod hahilulah.